# NodeJS require with asynch functions when synch is wanted

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, require, synchronous

I have the following code

```
var utils = require(`${__dirname}/../../utils/utils.js`);
...
let object = utils.parse(input);
    if (object === undefined){
        let helper = utils.recognize(input);
        msg.channel.sendMessage("\"" + input + "\" not recognized. Did you mean \"" + helper[0] + "\"?");
        object = utils.parse(helper[0]);
    }
//code related to object
console.log(object.strLength);
```

where "parse" tries to match the input to an object in a database, and "recognize" tries to find the best match if the input is spelled incorrectly (Levenshtein) (along with additional info such as how close the match was).

Currently the issue is that the code is ran asynchronously; "object.strLength" returns an undefined before utils.recognize() returns a value. If I copy/paste the recognize() and parse() functions into the file, then the code is run synchronously and I do not run into any issues. However I would rather keep those functions in a separate file as I reuse them in other files.

Is there a way to specify that the functions in utils must be synch? I know that there are libraries that convert asynch into synch but I prefer to use as few libraries as I can help it. I tried to have the recognize functions return a Promise but it ended up as a jumbled mess

edit: here's parse. I did not think it was necessary to answer this question so I did not include it initially:

```
var db = require(`${__dirname}/../data/database.js`);
...
var parse = (input) => {
    let output = db[output];
    if (output === null) {
        Object.keys(db).forEach((item) => {
            if (db[item].num === parseInt(input) || (db[item].color + db[item].type === input)){
                output = db[item];
                return false;
            }
        });      
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: You need to show us the code for utils.parse.

Comment: Uh, ok. Can't help but feel a little self-conscious with my variable names.

Comment: parse appears to be a perfectly synchronous method.  I don't see why it would sudden;y become async just because it's in a different module.  Something else is up in your code.

Comment: The `return false` from the inner loop looks very suspicious, since it negates the line before.

Comment: agreed,  I suspect parse is returning false when the asker doesn't expect it to.

Comment: It is possible for node to return a partially loaded module (for example, when a cyclic dependency is encountered).  It is possible that not all exports of that module are available at the point the code is attempted to be called.

Comment: `return false` simply breaks out of the forEach loop. PMV, that's interesting and I will investigate that. Perhaps I misdiagnosed the bug

Comment: So after a little poking around I found that if I stick a `console.log("hi");` in a very specific place in recognize() then everything works perfectly. Also, there is not and should not be any cyclic dependencies in any of my code.

Comment: While I did misunderstand the return false, it does not break the forEach loop.  Output could get assigned twice and you always look at all the keys.  You might want to use a different loop.   Don't think this causes your Async problem though.

Comment: @JsKingBoo `return false simply breaks out of the forEach loop` in jquery's `each`, but **not** in JS native `forEach` here it does absolutely nothing. same does `let output = db[output];` *(unless you have a property `db.undefined`)*. Maybe you mean `let output = db[input];`? and you talked about `"object.strLength" returns an undefined before utils.recognize() returns a value.` could you also show `utils.recognize()`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, thanks everyone. Here's what was wrong, it was with recognize(). It was my mistake to not show the code for it initially.

Original recognize:

```
var recognize = (item) => {

//iterate through our databases and get a best fit
let bestItem = null;
let bestScore = 99999; //arbitrary large number
//let bestType = null;

//found algorithm online by milot-mirdita
var levenshtein = function(a, b) {
    if (a.length == 0) { return b.length; } 
    if (b.length == 0) { return a.length; }

    // swap to save some memory O(min(a,b)) instead of O(a)
    if(a.length > b.length) {
        let tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp;
    }

    let row = [];
    for(let i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
        row[i] = i;
    }

    for (let i = 1; i <= b.length; i++) {
        let prev = i;
        for (let j = 1; j <= a.length; j++) {
            let val;
            if (b.charAt(i-1) == a.charAt(j-1)) {
                val = row[j-1]; // match
            } else {
                val = Math.min(row[j-1] + 1, // substitution
                        prev + 1,     // insertion
                        row[j] + 1);  // deletion
            }
            row[j - 1] = prev;
            prev = val;
        }
        row[a.length] = prev;
    }
    return row[a.length];
}   

//putting this here would make the code work
//console.log("hi");

Object.keys(db).forEach((key) => {
    if (levenshtein(item, key) < bestScore) {
        bestItem = key;
        bestScore = levenshtein(item, key);
    }
});

return [bestItem, bestScore];

}
```

My solution was to move the levenshtein function outside of the recognize function, so if I wanted to I can call levenshtein from another function

@user949300 and @Robert Moskal, I changed the forEach loop into a let...in loop. There is no functional difference (as far as I can tell) but the code does look cleaner.

@Thomas, I fixed the `let output = db[output];` issue, oops.

Again, thanks for all of your help, I appreciate it. And happy New Year too